# error al iniciar genymotion desde Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, virtualbox, genymotion

Instale el **Androis Studio 2.3.3** y el **genymotion 2.10.0**

Cuando uso el genymotion solo va perfecto, pero cuando intento usarlo desde el plugin de Android Studio me da un error al querer arrancar un dispositivo desde el Genymotion Device Manager, exactamente cuando selecciono un dispositivo y presiono el botón "Start"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luego de ir buscando por ahí, mire el log de Genymotion, observe que en al momento de llamar un Dispositivo Virtual desde el Android Studio, saltaba al tratar de ubicar unas librerias necesarias, en especifico este error

```
Output command: "/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxManage: ./libssl.so.1.0.0: version 'OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)"
```

AL buscarlo en Google me llevo a la repuestos de Stackoverflow en ingles en donde un Ingeniero de Genymotion explica que este error se produce por como define un path Android Studio.
Propone tres soluciones, yo aplique la que sugiere editar el studio.sh
En la linea 178 de mi studio.sh (Se encuentra en /opt/android-studio/bin/) esta la definición de LD_LIBRARY_PATH asi:

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$IDE_BIN_HOME$:LD_LIBRARY_PATH" "$JAVA_BIN" \

despues de editarla quedo asi:

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$IDE_BIN_HOME$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" "$JAVA_BIN" \

y todo listo ya puedo llamar mis dispositos virtuales de Genymotion desde el plugin de Android Studio.
aqui les dejo el enlace a Stackoverflow donde encontre la [respuesta de Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444327/genymotion-does-not-find-virtualbox-when-run-from-android-studio/42759651) que me ayudo.

Answer (score 0):

Debes de descargar Virtual Box para virtualizar los dispositivos android. Puedes descargarlo en la [pagina oficial de Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

Recuerda que android es un OS igual a todos y pueden virtualizarse. Normalmente todas las instalaciones de GENYMOTION incluyen la instalacion de virtual box(al menos en windows). Al parecer ignoraste el paso en la instalacion.

Comment: Gracias por tu respueta! No era por eso, pues si tengo VB instaldo, pero al revisar el log de genymotion vi un error lo busque y me llovo a esta entrada de stackoverflow  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444327/genymotion-does-not-find-virtualbox-when-run-from-android-studio/42759651 edite el studio.sh de Android Studio como dice ahi y listo

Comment: @RennyJoseGalindezFontecha Deberias agregar eso aqui como respuesta y aceptarla, asi le ayudaras a otros usuarios y ganaras reputación en el sitio

Comment: @jasilva gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo acá hay un tutorial de como instalar Genymotion [Instalar Genymotion](https://01luisrene.com/genymotion-potente-emulador-android/)

Recuerda Genymotion funciona con el software de virtualización Virtul Box.

Si realizas todos los pasos correctamente podrás disfrutar del emulador para Android.